# CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreate kCVReturnAllocationFailed

Tags: objective-c, macos, opengl, opengl-3

I am trying to create a CVOpenGLTextureCache  like this..

```
  NSOpenGLPixelFormatAttribute attrs[] =
    {
        NSOpenGLPFADoubleBuffer,
        NSOpenGLPFADepthSize, 32,
        NSOpenGLPFAOpenGLProfile,
        NSOpenGLProfileVersion3_2Core,
        0
    };
    NSOpenGLPixelFormat *pf = [[NSOpenGLPixelFormat alloc] initWithAttributes:attrs];

    if (!pf)
    {
        NSLog(@"No OpenGL pixel format");
    }
    m_glesCtx  = [[NSOpenGLContext alloc] initWithFormat:pf shareContext:nil];
    [(NSOpenGLContext*)m_glesCtx makeCurrentContext];

    CVReturn returnvalue = CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL, (CGLContextObj)this->m_glesCtx, [pf CGLPixelFormatObj], NULL, &this->m_textureCache);
```

But it always fails with error -6662 which is kCVReturnAllocationFailed.
Can anyone with some expertise in mac OpenGL help me to find out why it fails ..

Thanks for any help in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake..
Changed the statement

```
 CVReturn returnvalue = CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, NULL,(CGLContextObj)this->m_glesCtx, [pf CGLPixelFormatObj], NULL, &this->m_textureCache);
```

to

```
 CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, 0, [(NSOpenGLContext*)this->m_glesCtx CGLContextObj], [pf CGLPixelFormatObj], 0, &this->m_textureCache);
```

and every thing runs smooth.